# UrlMappingsTests - Could not load class in test type 'integration'?

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, url-mapping

I'm trying to create a UrlMappingsTest for my grails project, and I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load class in test type 'integration'
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

My class is pretty simple, and I tried to follow the example. What's going on?

```
import grails.test.GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase

class UrlMappingTests extends GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase {
//  static mappings = UrlMappings

  void testForwardingUrls(){
    assertForwardUrlMapping( "/rest/users/stefan/files", controller: "file", action: "allFiles" );
  }
}
```

With the static line uncommented, I get

```
  [groovyc] You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
  [groovyc] You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
  [groovyc] You attempted to use a method 'UrlMappings' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
  [groovyc]  @ line 7, column 21.
  [groovyc]      static mappings = UrlMappings
  [groovyc]       

             ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've logged a ticket on the [grails bugtracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-7319) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](http://plugins.grails.org/grails-testing/trunk/src/groovy/grails/test/GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase.groovy) for `GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase` you'll see that (as you maybe suspect) `static mappings = UrlMappings` isn't needed, since it does that by default if you don't specify a static mappings variable. Do you get a nested exception under the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load class in test type 'integration'` when you leave the line commented out? Post the full stacktrace, it should work. What version of grails are you using?

Comment: I get a class not found when I run without. I'm using 1.3.7

Comment: Hm okay I'm testing mine on 1.3.6 and it's working. Could you post the full stacktrace when you have it commented out?

Comment: I started a new project and this fails in 1.3.7. I suspect it's a regression.